# Closing a Toplevel() window from a seperate thread using Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, video, tkinter, python-multithreading

My Program uses VLC bindings to play a video while using the `time.sleep` function to wait until the video is over before playing the next video. It will play in a loop until the user presses a button and will only exit after that video is completed.

I am using `Threading` to handle the video playing as the `time.sleep` takes control away from the `root` window and the buttons are required to stop the video. Threading solves this.

My only problem is that the video needs to embed in a window. This window acts as an overlay to the main program (which serves an entirely different function) and removes flickering from the video when something updates underneath (this is when embeding the video directly into the `root` window.

I know `Threading` can't handle any of the GUI stuff that `Tkinter` makes, so I have tried to work around it. It works for the most part, it's just when it comes to destroying the window when or before the thread exits I am having trouble.

Below is some example code that opens a window and will then constantly count up and print the result until you tell it to stop (In the actual program it plays videos in the `Toplevel` window). There is an additional button to destroy the window. How can I get `Destroy` to run via the Thread (instead of the button)? Is it possible?

```
    from tkinter import *
    import os
    import threading
    import time

    root = Tk()

    class Player(Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):
            self.Playing = 0

        def Play(self):
            self.x = 0
            while self.Playing == 1:
                print(self.x)
                self.x = self.x + 1
                time.sleep(3)
                if self.Stopping == 1:
                    self.Playing = 0
                    sys.exit()

        def Go(self):
            if self.Playing == 0:
                self.Stopping = 0
                self.Playing = 1
                self.vidcanvas = Toplevel()
                self.vidcanvas.configure(bg='black')
                self.vidcanvas.geometry('200x200')
                self.th1 = threading.Thread(target=self.Play)
                self.th1.start()

        def Destroy(self):
            self.Stopping = 1
            self.vidcanvas.destroy()

        def Stop(self):
            self.Stopping = 1

    ply = Player(root)

    go = Button(root, text='Play', width=25, command=ply.Go)
    go.grid()
    stop = Button(root, text='Stop at End of Count', width=25, command=ply.Stop)
    stop.grid()
    stop = Button(root, text='Kill Window', width=25, command=ply.Destroy)
    stop.grid()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not sure what you asking, if you want to call `Destroy` from your thread and have it executed in Tk loop, consider using `after(0, self.Destroy)` instead of `sys.exit`.

Comment: If you want `Player` to actually inherit `Frame` (that is a GUI container to display something), you might consider to add `Frame.__init__(self, parent, **kw)` in `Player.__init__`

Comment: You hit the nail on the head with your first possible answer. I needed to close the window from the thread. Using `after(0, self.Destroy)` didn't work but `self.vidcanvas.after(0, self.Destroy)` worked perfectly. Can you explain why `after` works the way it does? If you write an answer I can mark it as correct. Thanks!